# Copy sheet with Macros to workbook in Python

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I've been looking for ways to do this and haven't found a good solution to this. I'm trying to copy a sheet in an .xlsx file that has macros to another workbook. I know I could do this if the sheet contained data in each cell but that's not the case. The sheet contains checkboxes and SOME text. Is there a way to do this in python (or any other language for that matter?) I just need it done programmatically as it will be part of a larger script.

Comment: I googled for [xlsxwriter macros](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_macros.html). Voting to close this as too broad because at this site questions are supposed to show a minimum level of research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try win32com package.
This offers an interface of VBA for python
You can find it on SourceForge.
I've done some projects with this package, we can discuss more on your problem if this package helps.